# I get this error when I try to install

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

[image]

[image]

```
The program 'winecfg' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install wine1.6
```

Comment: Well, have you tried running `sudo apt-get -f install` as the error suggested you do?

Comment: yes I did and still not set upped

Comment: @ahmadabdallah: Please [edit] your question to say that then and also please give the output of running that command.

Comment: Also, does running `sudo apt-get install kde-runtime` solve the problem?

Comment: it seems to be working now

Comment: For your latest problem please run `sudo apt-get install wine1.6` as it recommends.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running `sudo apt-get install -f` didn't work then try just installing the dependency it complains about manually:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-runtime
```

For the second dependency error you can just do the same as it recommends and:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

That should solve the issue. You can use `apt` instead of the `apt-get` part but they really do the same thing, `apt` might just have nicer colour-coding whereas `apt-get` is just plain.